# Google sheets "MODE" function for non-numeric values

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, counting, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to write a Google Sheets function that does the same as the MODE function, but for non-numeric values: returning the most frequently occuring string in a specified range.

I've searched the entire internet, and everywhere it's being suggested to use

```
=index(G2:L2, match(max(countif(G2:L2; G2:L2)), countif(G2:L2;G2:L2), 0))
```

or similar. This however returns an `#ERROR!`, which kind of leads me to believe that the correct syntax must have changed somehow… The range values are not even being highlighted in orange, as it usually does.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(A:A, "select A,count(A) group by A order by count(A) desc"), 2, 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: it's weird, I'm getting an error when copy-pasting the exact same code… https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DzphzS1bLc5U_4tUCc3GtwGi91cI4AfLCcpLu5rwrmY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: use: `=INDEX(QUERY(A:A; "select A,count(A) group by A order by count(A) desc"); 2; 1)`

Comment: ok great, this is working! is it possible to change the function to work on a different range (in my case, A2:D2)?

Comment: I'm also wondering why it needs a semicolon for me, but a comma seems to be working for you…

Comment: wow, okay, thanks for pointing this out! changing all commas to semicolons in the function from my question has resolved the issue… do you have any idea why it needs a different sign? is this an internationalization thing?

Comment: semicolon for you because you use German language in your spreadsheet settings

Comment: for A2:D2 use:  `=INDEX(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:D2); "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc"); 2; 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Replacing all commas (`,`) with semicolons (`;`) fixed the issue. I didn't know there were language specific syntaxes to the function language.

```
=index(G2:L2;match(max(countif(G2:L2;G2:L2));countif(G2:L2;G2:L2); 0))
```